# Which method is used to store cookie data into session file

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I am using a small PHP framework.

When calling `session_start()`, a class implementing `SessionHandlerInterface` 
allows a creation of the cookie file throught its method `read($id)`.

A file like `sess_533stse23wsdd23rs` is created on disk. Good.

Eventually a further call to the `SessionHandlerInterface` implementation writes more information in the cookie server file.  This information can be viewed on call to `write($id, $data)`.

When debugging, I break in the `write` method implementation and view the `call stack` and see a call from session_write_close().  I cannot discover where the data passed as parameter to the `write` is coming from.  I do not seem to have this info from the debugger.  This type of information is not accessible:

> session_write_close(){
>
> // Where this $data is coming from ?
>
> handler...write( $id, $data )
>
> }

In PHP, is there a method to save information to the cookie, so that a call to the session_write_close() will flush this information to the persistent file on disk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally, from what I discovered, it seems that any data in `$_SESSION` will be flushed to the cookie file.

Can I get somebody's confirmation ?